# Android app to upload a video to Wikimedia Commons (after re-encoding it if necessary)

Tags: gratis, android, video, media-converter, wikimedia-commons

[Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org) only accepts videos in the WebM and Theora formats, which is not the format most smartphones store videos in. [This means that re-encoding videos is necessary](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Converting_video) before uploading. Also, the web upload form easily gets reset on Android, so an app would probably be more reliable.

Requirements:

- Android app that uploads videos to Wikimedia Commons
- Before uploading, re-encodes videos to WebM (VP8 or VP9, latter preferred) or Ogg Theora
- Uploads in the background, so that I can do other things during that time
- Runs on Android 5+
- Free, ideally open source

Note: The [Commons Mobile app](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:Mobile_app) does not handle videos, only pictures.

Comment: Not an Android app, but there is another web app that fulfills most of your requirements: https://tools.wmflabs.org/videoconvert/index.php

Comment: @Ainali: Interesting! I guess that service could be used as the backend for an app.